# React Native Nested navigation default routing

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a react project with nested navigator, and observe a weird behaviour. The tab navigator can lead to the stack navigator pages (I simplified, the tab and the stack have more screens). It works, however the first screen from the stack that is displayed becomes the default that is shown when click on the tab 'Invest' button despite the initialRouteName parameter. So if the user clicks first on 'airdrop' in the dashboard, it becomes impossible to access the invest first screen without having a specific button on the airdrop page, which is pretty inconvenient (esp. as the stack actually has  pages or so). How can I solve that?

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTab() {
    const { language, theme } = useContext(JubileeContext );
    const iconSize = 24
    return ( 
    <Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={{
                activeTintColor: themes[theme].color2,
                labelStyle: { fontSize: 12 }
            }}
    >
        <Tab.Screen name="Dashboard" component={DashboardScreen} options={{
            tabBarLabel: strings[language].bottom_navbar.dashboard,
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
                <Icon name="gauge" color={color} size={iconSize} />
                ),
            }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen name="Invest" component={Invest} options={{
            tabBarLabel:strings[language].bottom_navbar.invest,
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Icon name="chart-line" color={color} size={iconSize} />
            ),
            }}
        />
    </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}

//Stack
const InvestStack = createStackNavigator( );
function Invest() {
    return(
        <InvestStack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false
            }}
            initialRouteName="Invest"
        >
            <InvestStack.Screen name="Invest" component={InvestScreen} />
            <InvestStack.Screen name="Airdrop" component={AirdropScreen} />
        </InvestStack.Navigator>
    );
}
```

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: Not really, it seems that the default behaviour can't be changed with any parameter, so I kept the bottom Tab Navigator, but re-implemented the bar rendered, so that I could manually define the behaviour of that button: in the tabBarOptions, I added tabBar={props => <MyTabBar {...props} />}, then in the state.routes.map, in the onPress(), added a if ( route.name == "Invest"){navigation.navigate('Invest', { screen: 'MainInvestScreen' }); }, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbar